# Change Title Of Page With The Click Of Anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using Javascript, how would I change the title of a page when a click a specific anchor tag.

```
<a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
<a href="about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a>
```

Possibly something like title="" in the anchor tags.  Also, if possible, could you have it support history, so that if the back or forward button is pushed, it would change back to what it was.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Revision: I have another plugin that dynamically changes the page, so clicking the links in the above statement doesn't actually change anything in the header.

Answer (score 2):

The current HTML code you provided will actually take the user to a different page upon clicking.  So depending on the title attribute of `index.html` and `about.html`, it may have different titles than the current page.

If you don't want the page to reload and add an entry into history, you could do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $('title').text($(this).attr('title'));
    history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can learn more about the `.pushState(...)` API here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Actually, it's `history.pushState(…)`, otherwise it results in a _is not a function_ error.

Comment: Good catch on the typo.  I've fixed the code example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `History.pushState()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

You can use it to push a new state to the browsers history like so:

```
var state = { 'page_id': 1, 'user_id': 5 };
var title = 'Hello World';
var url = 'hello-world.html';

history.pushState(state, title, url);
```

This should change the title and url and allow you to use the browsers back and forward functionality

To use this without requiring any outside libraries like jQuery you could add this to the `onclick` of the links, for example:

`<a href="index.html" title="Home" onclick="history.pushState({}, 'Home Page Title', 'home.html')">Home</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

       $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                $('title').text($(this).attr('title'));
                window.pushState({}, '', 'about.html');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });


</script>
</head>
<body>
<a  href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
<a href="about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a>

</body>
</html>
```